# How can I combine gradients on to work on opposite axes?

Tags: css

Essentially, I want to create an element that combines a "to right" gradient with a color stop at a certain percentage and another color stop for the remaining width with a "to bottom" gradient that fades both colors to transparent. Getting the color stop part is easy, getting the fade is easy; I just can't figure out how to get both.

[image: example of combined gradient effect]

```css
/*I can get this:*/

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.color-change {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 175,157) 80%, rgb(255, 95, 89) 80%);
}

/*or this:*/
  
.fade {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(252, 193, 176, 0), #fcc1b0);
  
  /* but not both*/
```

```html
<div class="color-change"></div>

<div class="fade"></div>
```

This probably isn't hard but I can't find any examples that do exactly this. I could just use a png., but it seems as though this ought to be doable in CSS. Thanks for any suggestions (or better, solutions).

Comment: Are you fine with using the `linear-gradient` with pseudo element?

Comment: I tried both suggestions and they would both work fine. The problem is that the element I was hoping to manipulate (already before and after pseudo elements) were intended to soften the sharp top and bottom of a div with scrolling content that is mostly the lighter color with the salmon color as a stripe. Despite using percentages as color stops, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the color change to line up pixel-perfect at all device sizes. And there also doesn't seem to be such a thing as an opacity gradient that would enable me to achieve the same outcome. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS **::before (:before)**

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of
> the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an
> element with the content property. It is inline by default. [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fade {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(252, 193, 176, 0), #fcc1b0);
  position: relative;
}

.fade::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(246,115,115,1) 4%, rgba(250,192,194,1) 34%, rgba(255,233,234,1) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);       
}
```

```html
<div class="fade"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple background layer can do it:

```css
.color-change {
  --p:80%; /* this is your percentage */
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fcc1b0) left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgb(255, 95, 89)) right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:var(--p) 100%,calc(100% - var(--p)) 100%;
  
  
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-change"></div>

<div class="color-change" style="--p:50%"></div>

<div class="color-change"  style="--p:20%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can mask it with a pseudo element. This is real transparent.

```css
body {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.color-change {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #000);
          mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #000);
  position: relative;
}

.color-change:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 175, 157) 80%, rgb(255, 95, 89) 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="color-change"></div>
```